# Extracting route variables directly from the request object in Play2/Scala

Tags: regex, scala, parsing, playframework, playframework-2.0

The only part of the Request class that I have found to contain relevant information is the request.tags map, specifically the `ROUTE_PATTERN` value. For example, in a route such as `/api/admin/:org/list` the route pattern is `/api/admin/$org<[^/]+>/list`. Is there a way to match request.path against this pattern and retrieve the "org" variable (and any other path variables)? Or any other way to retrieve this variable for that matter -- but, again: directly from the request object.

Please note that this needs to be generic; for instance, the route could have two parameters, or more, and the proposed method should be able to find all those when searched for.

Comment: How come you can't access the parameters as arguments to your controllers?

Comment: I can, but I've built some authZ decorators where I've been passing only the request object. I can add extra arguments but it becomes a mess, hence I'm trying to figure out if there's a better way.

Comment: I think you may be swimming against the current of where Play is trying to steer you. It's probably better to factor the concerns of auth out of your main controller logic. This is what https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActionsComposition is there for.